# Grafana develop a plugin without build it?

Tags: javascript, plugins, grafana

Good day all, I'd like to develop a simple plugin for Grafana, I don't want to redistribute it as it will be for internal use only.

May I simply write the plugin into the `/data/plugins/myplugin/dist/` folder?
I'd like not to use any build script like grunt or whatever.

Comment: In a word, yes.

Comment: Yes, but it's not advisable: not easy to manage with dependencies